# google api returns desired data when called via browser but gives countryBlocked error when called from curl in my application

Tags: php, google-api

I am new to yii and need to call the google's pagespeed API.
When I enter the following in the browser:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=mysite.com&key=myKey
```

I get what I want, but using the below code:

```
$client = new Client(['transport' => 'yii\httpclient\CurlTransport']);
$response = $client->createRequest()
    ->setMethod('get')
    ->setUrl('https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=mySite.com&key=myKey')
    ->setOptions([
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE=> 1,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 100, // connection timeout
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 100, // data receiving timeout
    ])
    ->send();
echo $response;
```

I gete:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"countryBlocked","message":"This service is not available from Iran. If you believe the country of origin was incorrectly identified, please report it at https://support.google.com/websearch/contact/ip."}],"code":403,"message":"This service is not available from Iran. If you believe the country of origin was incorrectly identified, please report it at https://support.google.com/websearch/contact/ip."}}
```

Comment: Is this from the same machine?

Comment: @JaredDunham, yes, they are from the same machine!

Comment: @scaisEdge, any solution sir?